# Where do me and you stand?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, pronouns, coordination

> 1. Where do me and you stand?

In the aforementioned sentence the pronoun 'me' used as subject doesn't seem to fit best; I mean, the problem that I see is that:

- The speaker should keep himself after the one he's talking to.
- The pronoun 'I' should be there.

So, in my opinion, the sentence should read:

> 2. Where do you and I stand?

Is my position correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes "Where do you and I stand?" is correct.  However, the use of "me" in forms like "you and me" is sufficiently common that it is doubtful whether it can truly be called 'wrong". It is "non-standard", at least.